# What is the minimum number of problems in the pool?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

Using a pool of problems, 16 tests will be formed, following certain conditions:

- Every test should have the same number of problems.
- Any problem should be included in at most 8 tests.
- Every group of 4 tests must share at least 1 problem.
- Each test may not use a single problem more than once.
- Some tests may have exactly the same problems.

What is the minimum number of problems in this pool?

As an example:

If this problem asked for 8 tests, where any problem could be included in at most 4 tests and at least 1 problem must be common to every 2 tests, then the answer would be 6 problems:

(1-2-6), (1-3-5), (1-3-5), (1-4-6), (2-3-6), (2-4-5), (2-4-5), (3-4-6)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this a question from some other source?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a question from https://www.puzzleup.com/2020/?home, a competition which explicitly the use of outside help :( Shame on you, helloworldx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: Found optimal solution**

Simple upper bound:

> 70: Group the tests in 8 pairs and create a problem for each group of 4 pairs. 8-choose-4 is 70.

Better upper bound:

> 50:
>  Rows are tests, columns are problems, "X" means problem is part of test, "." means not.
>
> ```
>  XXXXXXXX........X.X.....XX..XXXXX.X.....XX..XXXXX.
>  XXXXXXXX.........X.X......XXXXXX.X.X......XXXXXXX.
>  ........XXXXXXXXX.X.....XX..XXXX.X.X......XXXXXXX.
>  ........XXXXXXXX.X.X......XXXXXXX.X.....XX..XXXXX.
>  XXXX....XXXX....XXXXX.X.....XX..XXXXX.X.....XX...X
>  XXXX....XXXX....XXXX.X.X......XXXXXX.X.X......XX.X
>  ....XXXX....XXXXXXXXX.X.....XX..XXXX.X.X......XX.X
>  ....XXXX....XXXXXXXX.X.X......XXXXXXX.X.....XX...X
>  XX..XX..XX..XX..XX..XXXXX.X.....XX..XXXXX.X.....X.
>  XX..XX..XX..XX....XXXXXX.X.X......XXXXXX.X.X....X.
>  ..XX..XX..XX..XXXX..XXXXX.X.......XXXXXX.X.X....X.
>  ..XX..XX..XX..XX..XXXXXX.X.X....XX..XXXXX.X.....X.
>  X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.....XX..XXXXX.X.....XX..XXXXX.X..X
>  X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.......XXXXXX.X.X......XXXXXX.X.X.X
>  .X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X....XX..XXXXX.X.......XXXXXX.X.X.X
>  .X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X......XXXXXX.X.X....XX..XXXXX.X..X
> ```

Optimal solution:

> 30: Found using a simple stochastic greedy algorithm on a partial, hand crafted preset. Right panel is the same as left but with rows and columns rearranged as to make structural features easier to pick out.
>
> ```
>  XXXXXXXX.........XX..XXX...XX.    XXXX....XXXX....XXXX....X.X.X.
>  X.X..X.X.X.XX.X..XX..X..XXX..X    XXXX........XXXX....XXXXX.X.X.
>  .X.XX.X.X.X..X.X.XX..X..XXX..X    ....XXXXXXXX........XXXXX.X.X.
>  ........XXXXXXXX.XX..XXX...XX.    ....XXXX....XXXXXXXX....X.X.X.
>  XXXX....XXXX.....X.XX.XXXX....    XX..XX..XX..XX..XX..XX..X..X.X
>  XX....XX..XXXX..X.X.X..X.XX.X.    XX..XX....XX..XX..XX..XXX..X.X
>  ..XXXX..XX....XXX.X.X..X.XX.X.    ..XX..XXXX..XX....XX..XXX..X.X
>  ....XXXX....XXXX.X.XX.XXXX....    ..XX..XX..XX..XXXX..XX..X..X.X
>  XX..XX..XX..XX..X..X.X.XX.XX..    X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X..XX..X
>  X..X.XX.X..X.XX.X..X.XX..X..XX    X.X.X.X..X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX..X
>  .XX.X..X.XX.X..XX..X.XX..X..XX    .X.X.X.XX.X.X.X..X.X.X.X.XX..X
>  ..XX..XX..XX..XXX..X.X.XX.XX..    .X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.X.X.X..XX..X
>  X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X..X.XX.....XXXX    X..X.XX.X..X.XX.X..X.XX..X.XX.
>  X..XX..X.XX..XX.X.X.X.X.X..X.X    X..X.XX..XX.X..X.XX.X..X.X.XX.
>  .XX..XX.X..XX..XX.X.X.X.X..X.X    .XX.X..XX..X.XX..XX.X..X.X.XX.
>  .X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.....XXXX    .XX.X..X.XX.X..XX..X.XX..X.XX.
> ```

Structure and function:

> Going by the right panel we can split the tests into four groups of four and the problems into the first 24 and the last 6. The last 6 in handle all 4-tuples that are covered by at most two test groups, i.e. those that distrbute 4-0-0-0, 3-1-0-0 or 2-2-0-0 over the four test groups. Note the pattern of all six 2-subsets of 4 which we'll also see prominently on the 24 first problems.
>  The 24 deal with the remaining cases 2-1-1-0 and 1-1-1-1. They naturally split into 3 groups of 8 which differ by the way each group of four is split into two. The 3 groups are actually identical up to shuffling rows.
>  There is also symmetry between the two upper and the two lower groups of 4 tests. Either pair is identical up to rearrangment of tests.
>  Let us look a bit into how it covers both 2-1-1-0 and 1-1-1-1 creating some synergy. The obvious strategyof handling 1-1-1-1 is to cover each of the four test groups with a quarter of the allowed number of problem copies. In our case that would be 2, so 2 problems are needed to cover a test group and since there are 4 groups a total of $2^4 = 16$ problems is required.
>  This is what I have done manually in the non-optimal example above.
>  The 2-1-1-0 on the other hand has the additional requirement that one of test group features 2 times such that a simply covering the group is no longer enough. Instead all 6 2-subsets must be made available. Doing the naive thing --- using the 16-cover 3 times (one for each 2/4 covering) would require 48 problems, clearly too many, so how does this solution get away with half that? It uses a reduced version of 16-cover which doesn't reliably work since it uses only $2^3$ problems which is enough to cover 3 groups but not necessarily 4. The trick here is that it will always happen to work in one of the three groups of 8 because they cover all possible splits of a test group into two, in particular the one split that doesn't split the two tests from the same group.

Optimal because:

> We need only slightly improve @AxiomaticSystems's lower bound (26). Achieving 26 would amount to perfectly splitting the 16 tests into groups of 8 such that each group of 4 is contained in exactly one group of 8. Consider three tests a,b,c. They must share a problem with each of the remaining 13 tests. Because problems can only be used in 8 tests (5 other than a,b,c) a,b,c must have at least 3 problems in common. These three would optimally cover 15 tests other than a,b,c but since there are only 13 we waste two of them at a ratio of 15:13.

Comment: How did you arrive to this by a software?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Mostly by hand, but I used the computer (Python itertools and numpy) to check and make sure all groups of four a covered and also to set up regular subpatterns. For example, the first 16 columns are 4 groups of two pairs each. This gives 2^4 combinations. Those I let the computer generate.

Comment: Wow that must have taken ages!

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I'm certainly spending way too much time on this site. That said, this  one wasn't that bad; I just checked out a few ideas, and I don't expect this to be optimal.

Comment: +1 for the effort

Comment: @tehtmi It matters not since I have now found an optimal solution. And I checked the row and column sums. Still need to understand how it works, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to show that the minimal number of problems is at least

> 26

because

> if each number can appear at most 8 times, then it can be the common question for at most $\binom{8}{4}=70$ sets of 4 tests. However, there are $\binom{16}{4}=1820=70 \times 26$ of these in total.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though.